# What does "terms modulo" mean?

Tags: terminology

In "The Lambda Calculus - Its Syntax and Semantics" by H.P. Barendregt ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/919596927)) the term "term modulo" is used, E.g.

> The principal object of study in the λ-calculus is the set of lambda terms modulo convertibility. (p. 22)

> *Terms modulo a change of bound variables* (p. 25)

What does "terms modulo" mean?

Comment: It's not "terms modulo", it's "terms _modulo something_", or "x = y _modulo z_".  Are you familiar with $a = b \mod 3$?

Comment: [Meaning of "modulo the fact"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/meaning-of-modulo-the-fact).

Comment: This post seems to be useful as a duplicate, in the sense that it may help people find the post that it links to. Therefore, I've undeleted this post.